# MainActivity not found in Manifest file, but I declared it

Tags: android, android-activity

I am using Android Studio 3.2.I can't run android project by showing the error:

```
MainActivity not found in the Manifest file
```

but I also declare and then I can't also create new project. 
So, I am going to uninstall and reinstall android studio and clean android studio setting. But it doesn't work.

When I also create a new project following error showing:

```
> MyApplication\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

When I run and existing project this message is showing:

```
MainActivity not found in Manifest file
```

[image]

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: what does your colors.xml file look like? Maybe you entered a character there by accident

Comment: Try to use File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart for existing project.

Comment: No I don't entered any character in color.xml file. It just create a  new project, and encountered this error.

Comment: @Jack Herbert : Have you mentioned 'package="com.yourpackage.applicationname' in manifest file as outlined by Bhuvaneshwaran

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.yourpackage.applicationname">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm first line in your colors.xml is  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`?

The error hint `Error: Content is not allowed in prolog` had show reason that you can't run this APP.